# how to use v-for index as value for href

Tags: vue.js, href, v-for

I am using VueJS along with foundation css. I am trying to create an accordion from a v-for loop. However VueJS wants me to bind the href to the projectIndex variable.

I have tried creating a projectIndex parameter and then using a computed property to return a concatenation of  "#" + projectIndex, but projectIndex is always undefined.

```
data: {
        projectIndex: ''
}
```

....

```
computed:{
                projectHref: function () {
                    return "#" + this.projectIndex;
                }
            }
```

Out of interest I am using `[[]]` rather than `{{}}` because I am also using twig which shares the same `{{}}` as VueJS

```
 <ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
                    <li class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(priceData, projectIndex) in prices">
                        <a href="#[[projectIndex]]">Price Project: [[priceData.meta.project.name]]</a>
                        <div id="[[projectHref]]">
                            <div v-for="(prices, supplier) in priceData.prices">
                                <h6>[[supplier|SupplierKeyName]] ([[supplier|SupplierKeyCode]])</h6>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td v-for="(price, priceBreak) in prices">[[priceBreak]]</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td v-for="(price, priceBreak) in prices">[[price.currency]][[price.price]]</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

is the `prices` variable already set?

if yes, then I think it is replaced by your second `v-for` that use same `prices` variable, so that the for loop breaks away

```
//here is the first 'prices' variable
<li class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(priceData, projectIndex) in prices">
    <a href="#[[projectIndex]]">Price Project: [[priceData.meta.project.name]]</a>
        <div id="[[projectHref]]">
             //here the prices variable is replaced
             <div v-for="(prices, supplier) in priceData.prices">
```

try to differentiate those vars

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. I can now bind projectIndex to my href. However the property projectIndex is never updated, so my computed property only ever returns "#" rather than "#1", any idea how I can use projectIndex in the computed property?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. I found that I could bind to a method and pass projectIndex in as a value. like so

```
 <li class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(priceData, projectIndex) in prices">
                    <a :href="projectHref(projectIndex)">Price Project: [[priceData.meta.project.name]]</a>
```

My method then returns the concatonation that I needed.

```
methods: {
 projectHref: function (index) {
                    return "#" + index.toString();
                }
}
```